# How to delete data in the current page then redirecting to another page with a back button

Tags: php, html, mysqli

My current page is `displayitems.php`. I got a button `type='hidden'` with a style and a background image of the button and a hidden input type='hidden .'

I can retrieve the id of the image when clicked. Whenever I click on the button (with image) it displays the the exact image of the button in another page which is `userdetails.php` and I got a back button that will redirect to displayitems.php.

Now my problem here is if I click another button (image) it display the past image instead of a new one can any of you delete the past image then display the current button that I click

This is my homepage

```
<?php
  require 'header.php';
?>
  <main>
<?php
  require 'uploaditems.php';
  echo "<br>";
  require 'loginlogout.php';
  echo "<div>";
  require 'displayitems.php';
  echo "</div>";
?>
</main>
```

My displayitems.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
   require "includes/dbh.php";
   ?>
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" href="style.php"/>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <style>
      .product{
          border:1px solid
          margin:-1px 19px 3px -1px;
          padding: 10px;
          text-align:center;
          bacgkround-color:#efefef;
      }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
    include_once 'includes/dbh.php';

    $sql="SELECT * FROM gallery ORDER BY orderitems DESC;";
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){
       echo "sql statement failed in displayitems.php";            
    }else{
       mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
       $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

          while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
             ?>
             <div class="col-md-3">
             <form method="POST" action="userdetails.php">
               <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value=<?php echo $row['idGallery'];?>>
               <div class="product" style="float: left;">
                 <button type="hidden" name='displaydetails' 
                 style='background- 
   image:url(images/<?php echo $row['imgFullNameGallery'];?>
  );width:150px; height:200px; margin:auto; background-size:100% 100%; b 
   ackground-repeat:no-repeat;>
                 </button>
             </form>';
             <br>
             <br><br><h3><?php echo $row['nameitem']?></h3>
             <h3><?php echo $row['price']?></h3>
             <br>
             </div>
             </div>
             <?php
         }
      }
   }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

and my userdetails.php

```
  <?php
    session_start();
  if(isset($_POST['displaydetails'])){
 if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){
```

This is how I got the hidden id of the image

```
  $idofimg=$_POST['hiddenId'];
  require 'includes/dbh.php';
```

And i've created a query where I want all the data of the hidden id

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE idGallery=? ;";
  $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt,$sql)){

 echo "sql statement failed in displayitems.php";            
 }else{
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'i',$idofimg);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
   $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
   if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
   while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
         <title>Page Title</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
 scale=1">
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" 
   href="main.css" />
         <script src="main.js"></script>
     </head>   
     <body>
           <img src="images/<?php echo $row['imgFullNameGallery'];?>" style 
   =width:330px; height:300px; margin:auto; background-size:100% 100%; 
   background-repeat:no-repeat;>
         <div>
        <h3>Details</h3>
         <table>

             <tr>
                <td>Condition:</td>
                 <td>ha</td>
           </tr>
    </div>
```

This is where I want to put my condition where I will delete all this current data and go back to index2.php and then when clicked another image button it will display the current image not the past image

```
     <form action='index2.php' method='POST'>
      <button type='submit'>BACK</button>
      <?php
    $count=1;
       ?>
       </form>
       <?php
     }
    }   
      }

  } else{
  echo "fail";
  }}
 ?>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: it's not clear what your actual problem is: how to delete an item from the database?

Comment: No i want to delete or remove the current data in userdetails,php and when I click back it goes to another page which is displayitems.php then when I click another image it display the past image instead of a new one since I have no condition in the back button form in userdetails.php because i dont know how to do it

Comment: right now you don't delete or remove anything - to start with. So is this part of the question?

Comment: thats what im trying to figure out if how  can I remove it

Comment: Jenel, it's very unclear what you want to do. You are mentioning both "delete" and "hide" in your question. Are you asking on how to remove an element from the DOM? Also the above code blocks you've posted are very unclear as well.

Comment: Im sorry sir Jeff for ex. each button in displayitems.php has its own id and I get that to display all the information related in that id in my database. Then i display all the details in it. Now I want to remove the details when I click back in userdetails.php its like resetting all the data in the userdetails.php because I want to generate another details when I click another button in the displayitems.php but whenever I click different buttons in displayitems.php it display the past image or past details of the id not the current button that I've clicked which has a different id as well

Comment: _"I want to remove"_ as in "delete from database" or "not show in html"? When you hit "Back" you just redirect to "display_items.php", which does nothing but show _all_ items in database. Still unclear. Try to reduce your problem to smaller steps. Try to create a minimal example of _one_ thing it should do, one after each other.

Answer (score 0):

here in my displayitems.php my input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value=> is only getting 1 value when the  button type="hidden" name='displaydetails'> is not getting any value when clicked. So when I go to userdetails.php it only display 1 details because of the input type. so I should remove the input type in displayitems.php and just give the button a value so whenever it was click it will generate a new id and display also a new details.

just change this to displayitems.php

```
  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" value=<?php echo $row['idGallery'];?>>
           <div class="product" style="float: left;">
             <button type="hidden" name='displaydetails' 
                style='background- 

                image:url(images/<?php echo $row['imgFullNameGallery'];?>
              );width:150px; height:200px; margin:auto; background-size:100% 100%; b 
             ackground-repeat:no-repeat;>
                 </button>
```

to this

```
              <div class="product" style="float: left;">
               <button type="hidden" name='displaydetails' value=<?php echo 
   $row['idGallery'];?> 
                style='background- 
    image:url(images/<?php echo $row['imgFullNameGallery'];?>
     );width:150px; height:200px; margin:auto; background-size:100% 100%; b 
    ackground-repeat:no-repeat;>
                </button>
```

and to userdetails.php

```
     if(isset($_POST['displaydetails'])){
  if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){

 $idofimg=$_POST['hiddenId'];
```

to this

```
 if(isset($_POST['displaydetails'])){
     if(isset($_SESSION['userId'])){

  $idofimg=$_POST['displaydetails'];
```